# How to serialize a Dictionary<object, guid>?

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization

I'm currently building an application where I have some tasks that are sharing a Dictionary<Object, Guid>.

To avoid conflicts, the actual Dictionaries are contained within a DictionaryHandler-class with three methods:

```
class DictionaryHandler
{
    
    private object lockProcesses = new object();
    private Dictionary<Process, Guid> processes = new Dictionary<Process, Guid>();

    public Dictionary<Process, Guid> GetProcesses()
    {
        lock (lockProcesses)
        {
            // TODO
        }   
    }

    public void AddToProcesses(Process process, Guid guid)
    {
        lock (lockProcesses)
        {
            processes.Add(process, guid);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveFromProcesses(Process process)
    {
        lock (lockProcesses)
        {
            processes.Remove(process);
        }
    }
}
```

For context, this is the Process-class:

```
public class Process
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public bool Enabled { get; }
    public TimeSpan RuntimeWindowStart { get; }
    public TimeSpan RuntimeWindowEnd { get; }
    public TimeSpan Cooldown { get; }
    public int Priority { get; }
    public string Username { get; }
    public string ExceptionDate { get; }
    public string ExceptionDay { get; }
    public string AllowedWorkdays { get; }
    public string SpecificResource { get; }
    public string Assigned { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }

    public Process(string name, bool enabled, TimeSpan runtimeWindowStart, TimeSpan runtimeWindowEnd, TimeSpan cooldown, int priority, string username, string exceptionDate, string exceptionDay, string allowedWorkdays, string specificResource, string assigned, DateTime? timestamp)
    {
        Name = name;
        Enabled = enabled;
        RuntimeWindowStart = runtimeWindowStart;
        RuntimeWindowEnd = runtimeWindowEnd;
        Cooldown = cooldown;
        Priority = priority;
        Username = username;
        ExceptionDate = exceptionDate;
        ExceptionDay = exceptionDay;
        AllowedWorkdays = allowedWorkdays;
        SpecificResource = specificResource;
        Assigned = assigned;
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

My main issue is that I want to find a way to return a copy of the Dictionary through the GetProcesses()-method, without returning a reference to the "actual" dictionary.

As far as I can see, the optimal way to do this is to Serialize and Deserialize the Dictionary and return that. But I'm having a hard time doing this, as I'm unable to find an example that matches my case.

I've read [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) and [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) and tried to combine the two - unfortunately without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main issue is that I want to find a way to return a copy of the Dictionary through the GetProcesses()-method, without returning a reference to the "actual" dictionary.

If you don't need to clone the values, you can use the constructor overload to Dictionary which takes an existing IDictionary:

```
new Dictionary<Process, Guid>(processes);
```

If you do need to clone the values, you can use something like:

```
public static Dictionary<Process, Guid> DeepClone<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<Process, Guid> source)
{
    var ret = new Dictionary<Process, Guid>(source.Count, source.Comparer);
    foreach (var entry in source)
    {
        ret.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you do need create a copy of `Process` class instance while copying dictionary, you may use:

```
public class Process
{
    // some properties here

    public Process ShallowCopy()
    {
        return (Process) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}


public static Dictionary<Process, Guid> DeepClone<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<Process, Guid> source)
{
    var ret = new Dictionary<Process, Guid>(source.Count, source.Comparer);
    foreach (var entry in source)
    {
        ret.Add(entry.Key.ShallowCopy(), entry.Value);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Awesome - This is exactly what I needed - Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String` instead of `Guid`.

---

Guid is structure type. Therefore serialize and deserialize methods might not work correctly.